# .Net Async methods in PowerShell: Net.Mail.SmtpClient::Send() not always synchronous? (inconsistent via scheduled task)

Tags: .net, email, powershell, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

### Problem:

PowerShell script that sends email works when invoked from an interactive session, but fails when invoked via Scheduled Task.  This seems to be caused by the SMTP session being interrupted mid-transmission when the script exits.  Naturally, this doesn't happen during an interactive session because the session continues to live after the script ends.  However, the session is killed at the end of the script when invoked via scheduled task.

Script:

```
    $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    foreach( $To in $Recipients ) {
      $msg.To.Add($To)
    }
    $msg.From = $From
    $msg.Subject = $Subject
    $msg.Body = $Body
    $ctype = New-Object Net.Mime.ContentType -Property @{
      MediaType = [Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames+Application]::Octet
      Name = $AttachmentName
    }
    $msg.Attachments.Add([Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString($csv, $ctype))
    $client = new-object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)
    $client.Send($msg)
```

### Question

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient::Send() is supposed to be synchronous, but it's not working out that way in practice.  I know that I can mitigate this somewhat by having the script sleep for a short time at the end of the script.  Frankly, that is some seriously sloppy work and I refuse to do it that way.  What is the best workaround?

Note: `Send-MailMessage` is not appropriate because I prefer to avoid creating a file in order to make the attachment.  I am not sure if it suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution: SendAsync()

It's unfortunate that the `Send()` is not as synchronous as the documentation claims.  I have found it most beneficial to instead use the asynchronous variant `SendAsync()` and use the `SendCompleted` event to provide synchronicity.  Please see the following general purpose function that I wrote to solve this very problem (although it could be used for a variety of async calls):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
  Calls a script block and waits for the specified event.
.DESCRIPTION
  Provides a convenient way to call an asynchronous method with synchronous semantics.
  This is achieved by registering to receive an event before calling the block that is
  expected to signal its completion via a .NET event.  The given script block need not
  necessarily cause the event to be signaled, but that is the most obvious use case.
.PARAMETER EventSource
  The object expected to raise the event.
.PARAMETER EventName
  The name of the expected event.
.PARAMETER ScriptBlock
  This block will be executed after registering the event and before waiting for the event.
.PARAMETER Timeout
  Maximum duration in seconds to wait for the expected event.  Default value of -1 means
  to wait indefinitely.  No error is raised when this timeout is reached.
.NOTES
  Author:  Erik Elmore <erik@ironsavior.net>
#>
function Wait-AsyncCall {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0)]
    $EventSource,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 1)]
    [string]$EventName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 2)]
    [ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock,
    [int]$Timeout = -1
  )
  $id = "Wait-AsyncCall:$($EventName):$([guid]::NewGuid().ToString())"
  Register-ObjectEvent $EventSource $EventName -SourceIdentifier $id -EA Stop
  try {
    $output = &$ScriptBlock
    Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier $id -Timeout $Timeout -EA SilentlyContinue |Remove-Event -EA SilentlyContinue
  }
  finally {
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $id -EA SilentlyContinue
  }
  $output
}
```

Using `Wait-AsyncCall`, I can instead use the `AsyncSend()` method, but with synchronous semantics.  The original code block then becomes:

```
$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
foreach( $To in $Recipients ) {
  $msg.To.Add($To)
}
$msg.From = $From
$msg.Subject = $Subject
$msg.Body = $Body
$ctype = New-Object Net.Mime.ContentType -Property @{
  MediaType = [Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames+Application]::Octet
  Name = $AttachmentName
}
$msg.Attachments.Add([Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString($csv, $ctype))
$client = new-object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)
Wait-AsyncCall $client "SendCompleted" { $client.SendAsync($msg, $Null) }
```